# how to compute $[x^n]A(x)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> Given that $A(x) = \frac{8 +14x-50x^2}{(1-7x^2+6x^3)}$
>
> compute $[x^n]A(x)$

Using a generating function $A(x) = \sum_{i=0} a_kx^k $
I get $a_n - 7a_{n-2} + 6a_{n-3} = 0,  n>= 3$

How do I now compute $[x^n]A(x)$?

Comment: Try decomposing $A(X)$ into its partial fractions

Comment: What is the sticking point: relating $[x^n] A(x)$ to $a_n$ or solving the linear recurrence?

Answer (score 2):

Throwing it at Wolfy,
$1-7x^2+6x^3
=(-1 + x) (-1 + 2 x) (1 + 3 x) 
$.

Since all the roots are simple,
you can now do
a partial fraction decomposition
$\dfrac1{1-7x^2+6x^3}
=\dfrac{a}{-1+x}+\dfrac{b}{-1+2x}+\dfrac{c}{1+3x}
$
to get the power series for
$ \dfrac{8 +14x-50x^2}{(1-7x^2+6x^3)}
$.

Comment: I don't understand what to do once we have the partial fraction decomp, how do i find the coefficient for [x^n]

Comment: @KevinG  There's two ways to do this: 1) You can determine $A^{(n)}(x)/n!$ at $x=0$ (look at the generating function, and what differentiating it does), or 2) try to calculate the series expansion of $\dfrac{a}{-1+bx}$ directly (geometric sum)